# Trying to sort specific columns in linux

Tags: linux, sort

I have been trying to sort specific columns with some data I have which is:

```
ID Name Last Grade      
123 Bill Holy A   
747 Chloe Crown B    
757 Aaron Farmer D    
365 Gray Billson
```

Column by column I'm trying to sort the first column (ID) in numerical order, sort the second column (Name) in alphabetical order while all other peices of data are left as they are. I'd like to do this in one whole command. 
So far I have tried 
`sort -k1,1 -k2,2 [filename]`, but all this did was sort the first column in numerical order but the second column (Name) did not appear to have changed or have been sorted in anyway. Lastly when I ran this command it made the headers (**ID, Name, Last, Grade**) move to the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example containes unique field 1 values (the ID number) so if the data is sorted by ID, subsequently sorting by name will have no effect.

The sort program sorts the entire file, without looking for header lines...

The following Awk program prints the header line, and sends all subsequent lines to sort.

```
awk '{if (NR==1) {print $0} {print $0 | "sort -k1,1 -k2,2"}}' <filename>
```

Comment: `head -n1 <filename>; tail +2 <filename> | sort -k1,1n -k2,2`

Comment: @MichaelD. Two ways to skin a cat

Comment: @MichaelD.- on a GNU system that could further be simplified to `{ head -n1; sort -k1,1 -k2,2; } < file_name`

Comment: @iruvar That works in bash - but why?

Comment: @CharlesGreen, that's because when the input file is seekable(like in this case), GNU `head` ensures the file offset in the open file description is properly positioned past the last byte that was processed (so in this particular instance `head` leaves the file offset at the beginning of line 2 thereby teeing things up nicely for `sort`). BTW, shouldn't your `awk` solution be doing a `{print $0; next}` instead of just a `{print $0}` when `NR ==1`?

Comment: @iruvar I'm a brand-new awk user, so all I can say is that it works...  I think the 'next' is superfluous, as the construct if the 'if' statement is satisfied by the simple '{print $0}' action

Comment: @CharlesGreen, you need to invoke `next` after `print` when `NR == 1` to prevent the first line from being fed down to `sort` by the next statement

Comment: @iruvar It is easier to read as `awk '{if (NR==1) {print $0} else {print $0 | "sort -k1,1 -k2,2"}}'` where the `else` is explicity called out

Comment: @CharlesGreen i see so basically sort, thinks the ID numbers and the Names are one bit of data so hence it sorts it all together and does not let me sort each separate field. So is there any way i could sort each specific column or not?

Comment: The ID and the Names are distinct columns (numbers 1 and 2, number 3 is the last name) - but if each student has a unique ID, then sorting on the ID is kind of a canonical sort.  For readability, I would sort column 3 and column 2, so the results would be sorted by last name, and then by first name.

Comment: @CharlesGreen so basically your saying there's no point in changing the ID and names because they are connected, if they make sense, so if i wanted to change a column the next column would stick next to it and change too along with it?

Comment: @Qasim Kind of - If the ID is unique, then using that as the primary sort key will define the way that all of the rows are sorted.  A secondary sort key is useful if the primary key contains duplicates.  If you had, for example, the first name as the primary key, and there were three people in the list with the name Qasim, then a secondary key *could* be used to sort by ID, or by last name.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Okay i see, So what would be the option to add a secondary key i have never heard of secondary keys only primary keys,  -k followed by the column number.

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed and sort :

```
sed -z 'h;s/\n.*//;x;s/[^\n]*\n//;s/.*/echo "&"|sort -k1,1 -k2,2/e;x;G' infile
```